# Get recipient addresses of all messages in exchange online via Powershell

Tags: powershell, message

I've used a catch-all mailbox so far. I registered every account with a different mail address e.g. stackoverflow.com@mydDomain.de

Since I just switched to O365 I want to create aliases for all accounts so far. I imported all my mails to O365 and I need to get all the recipient-addresses I ever used.

So I need a Powershell Script to loop through all messaages within my O365 Mailsbox to extract the Mail recpient.

I experimented with the get-MessageTrace and it seems to be working:

```
$dateOBJ = (Get-Date).Adddays(-30);
$allRecipientsARY = Get-MessageTrace -StartDate $dateOBJ -EndDate (Get-Date) | Group-Object -Property RecipientAddress | Select name

$recipientsARY = @()

ForEach ($recipientSTR in $allRecipientsARY)
{
    if($recipientSTR -like '*myDomain.com*')
    {
        $recipientsARY = $recipientsARY + $recipientSTR
    }
}

$recipientsARY | Export-Csv c:\temp\mailAddresses.csv –NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

The problem is that the get-MessageTrace function only supports mails 30 days back from current date.

Is there an alternative? So far I haven't found one...

-thx
Dave

Comment: From what i can see, the specified cmdlet (et others) are for managing the O356 mailboxes from an administrator perspective. For reading it from a client perspective you need to use the appropriate api like the outlook/O356 graph api endpoint: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph/quick-start . I've also seen people here suggest the EWS api, but i have no experience with that in combination with O356 of outlook.com.

Comment: Actually I don't care which API I use, since I have only one account here (and this is the admin account)